# Chrome browser history preventing url redirect

Tags: google-chrome, dns, history, cname

I changed my CNAME from domain.com to www.domain.com. I added a URL redirect that forwards domain.com to www.domain.com.

I am facing an issue due to Chrome's browser history cache. If I visit domain.com, it says the website is not available. If I clear my browser history and visit domain.com it redirects properly to www.domain.com. This is an issue for me because everyone that visited my website before will now view it as unavailable. What should I do?

Note: I changed the CNAME because it conflicted with my MX.

EDIT:

I think the issue is the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444780/rails-activating-ssl-support-gets-chrome-confused

Comment: Please share your full zonefile or the name of the domain as that makes it so much easier help us debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you lack an understanding of how DNS works.

(You should never have a CNAME for a base record, unless you know *exactly what its doing - I guess you've found that one out !).

You still need a record for the basename for it to find the IP of the address to redirect to.  This needs to be an A record though (ie an IP address), not a CNAME.   Its a sucky limitation of how DNS works.

Another thing is that caching DNS is something that happens at multiple levels, and is par for the course.  You should expect caching of a record in the browser (normally until it closes, but depends on a lot of things like browser, TTL's in the domain name), the nameservers in your router, your upstream ISP's nameservers and other nameservers on the Internet.